# R use gsub as substr

Tags: regex, r, gsub, h2o

I'm using H2O for some distributed computing work (via the `h2o` package in R).  Many of the base R functions are present but I'm unable to find a suitable substitute for the `substr` function.  I do have access to the `sub` and `gsub` functions and was hoping to possibly use some form of regex as a workaround.

I'm using the following code but not having any luck:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = seq(14102201,14103200, 100))
    df1$var2 <- substr(df1$var1, 1,6)
    df1$var3 <- gsub('\\d{1,8}','\\d{1,6}', df1$var1)
    df1
```

The output in `df1$var2` is what I'm looking for.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Running this code:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init(nthreads = 2) 
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = seq(14102201,14103200, 100))
df1.hex <- as.h2o(localH2O , df1)
df1.hex$var2 <- substr(df1.hex$var1, 1, 6)
```

Gets this message:

```
> df1.hex$var2 <- substr(df1.hex$var1, 1, 6)
Error in as.character.default(x) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Comment: What's wrong with `substr()`? It's clean does what you want.  Are you concerned about efficiency?

Comment: @RichardScriven: It doesn't work with an H2O object.

Comment: Just curious, what is the error it triggers? I ask because `gsub` and `substr` use the same argument checks

Comment: @RichardScriven: see edit above.

Answer (score 3):

Use capture groups:

```
gsub('(.+)..','\\1', df1$var1)
```

This regex matches (.+).. with `df1$var1`, and replace it with the substring that matches the first capture group `(.+)`. Since there is `..` at the end of the regex, the last two characters are not matched with the `.+`, thus they are not in the result.

Comment: This trims the last 2 elements from the string, which in this case, happens leave the first 6.

Comment: `gsub('(.{6}).*','\\1', df1$var1)` is a more literal translation of `substr(x,1,6)` .

Answer (score 1):

Capture the first 6 value like so using a pattern that matches the whole sting

```
gsub('^(.{6}).*$','\\1', df1$var1)
```

A slightly more general replacement for `substr(x,start,stop)` is

```
if(start > 1)
     gsub('^(.{*start-1*})(.{*stop-start+1*})).*$','\\1', 'asdfhjkl')
else
     gsub('^(.{*stop*})).*$','\\1', 'asdfhjkl')
```

where the values between the `*` characters are the actual integer values of the expression.  (although you'll have to make sure that `nchar(x)`is less than `stop`, otherwise the patterns won't match b/c the string is too short.)

Answer (score 1):

The regex `(?<=^.{6}).*$` matches al characters after the first 6 ones. If you want to replace `substr(df1$var1, 1, 6)` with `sub`, you can use this command:

```
sub('(?<=^.{6}).*$', '', df1$var1, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "141022" "141023" "141024" "141025" "141026" "141027" "141028" "141029"
# [9] "141030" "141031"
```

This command replaces all digits after the first 6 ones with the empty string.